# Xml schema validation does not fail on trailing line-feed

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, .net-core

Using the XmlReader, I'm performing schema validation on XML elements who's datatype does not allow line-feeds. If the value contains a line-feed at the beginning or anywhere before the end of the string, schema validation fails as expected. If the value ends with space before the line-feed, it fails schema. Only when the line-feed is at the end of the string does the schema validation not fail. I believe that it should fail.

Here is an example schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="StringContent" type="an" />
    <xs:simpleType name="an">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[ !-~]*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is example code:

```
var xmlSchemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
xmlSchemaSet.Add(XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(schema),  
        (sender, args) => { Console.WriteLine(args.Exception.Message); }));

var xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings
{
    ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema,
    Schemas = xmlSchemaSet
};

xmlReaderSettings.ValidationEventHandler += 
    delegate (object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
         {
            Console.WriteLine($"{description}: {args.Exception.Message}"); 
         };

var xmlDateReader = XmlReader.Create(
    new StringReader("<StringContent>some string content\n</StringContent>"), xmlReaderSettings);

while (xmlDateReader.Read()) { }
```

The actual schema that we are using is managed by a standards body, and as a result, I am unable to change it.   Is there a way to get the XmlReader to correctly fail schema validation when there is a trailing linefeed?

Comment: please state clearly what your question is - thank you

Comment: updated by clarifying the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:pattern value="[\w]+"/>
```

### [\w]+

Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation) «[\w]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»

Validation is done based on the schema, if you do not own the schema and cannot change it, then comply with it's rules or negotiate with the party that gave you the schema.

To match only strings that do not contain an LF use:

### [^\n]+

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I am unable to change the schema.  We're contractually obligated to use a schema that is managed by a standards body.  But thanks for the suggestion.  It's interesting that that works.

Comment: So I ran some tests with [\w]+.  If the string contains spaces it fails schema validation. If its just a string with no spaces and a trailing linefeed it does not fail schema validation.

Comment: Validation us done based on the schema, if you do not own the schema and cannot change it, then comply with it's rules or negotiate with the party that gave you the schema. See the updated answer, for an additional regular expression.

Comment: @Kris I appreciate the engagement.   If I update the code above with the pattern [^\n]+, the text 'some string content\n' still does not fail schema validation.